# sql query to pull 2 clients per provider in random sequence

Tags: sql, reporting-services

Is there a way for sql query to pull 2 clients per provider in random sequence? I have my query set up to provide distinct list of providers.I also have a separate query set up to pull random 2 clients.I want to combine these two queries for the sake of creating a report in SSRS. Is there a way to create the report using 2 datasets? or I cannot move forward without combining the 2 queries?

query to pull distinct provider

```
SELECT distinct provider_mstr.description 
FROM person 
INNER JOIN charges ON person.person_id = charges.person_id 
full JOIN provider_mstr ON provider_mstr.provider_id = charges.rendering_id 
where provider_mstr.delete_ind <> 'Y'
```

Query to pull 2 random clients :

```
SELECT top 2 person.last_name + ', ' + person.first_name + ' ' + person.middle_name as 'Client', 
FROM person 
INNER JOIN charges ON person.person_id = charges.person_id 
INNER JOIN service_item_mstr ON charges.service_item_lib_id = service_item_mstr.service_item_lib_id 
FULL OUTER JOIN provider_mstr ON provider_mstr.provider_id = charges.rendering_id 
WHERE provider_mstr.delete_ind <> 'Y' and charges.amt > 0.01 and 
order by newid()
```

Comment: What are the queries? So we can help you with the combine

Comment: Instead of putting comment, edit the question with the queries and format it as code select the text and press `ctrl-k`  or add 4 spaces before each line

Comment: @user8909298 -- I added your queries in but these have syntax errors.  it is more useful to post queries that work.

Answer (score 0):

as below with your syntax error queries:

```
SELECT distinct provider_mstr.description as provider, null as Client
FROM person 
INNER JOIN charges ON person.person_id = charges.person_id 
full JOIN provider_mstr ON provider_mstr.provider_id = charges.rendering_id 
where provider_mstr.delete_ind <> 'Y' 

union all 

SELECT top 2 null as provider, person.last_name + ', ' + person.first_name + ' ' + person.middle_name as Client 
FROM person 
INNER JOIN charges ON person.person_id = charges.person_id 
INNER JOIN service_item_mstr ON charges.service_item_lib_id = service_item_mstr.service_item_lib_id 
FULL OUTER JOIN provider_mstr ON provider_mstr.provider_id = charges.rendering_id 
WHERE provider_mstr.delete_ind <> 'Y' and charges.amt > 0.01 and 
order by newid()
```

---

original answer here:

```
--<sql for query1>

UNION ALL

--<sql for query2>
```

The columns will have to be the same number and type in both queries.

You might need to use null as in this example

```
 SELECT 1 as NUM1, 2 as NUM2, null as VC1, null as VC2
 FROM -- etc

 UNION ALL

 SELECT null as NUM1, null as NUM2, 'A' as VC1, 'B' as VC2
 FROM -- ect
```

Comment: OP want two clients for provider

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza -- I don't know what you think the OP means by "clients"  I assumed a resulting row was a client here.  Given there is no more detail this is best I can do.

Comment: Is ok, I just was trying to give a heads up so dont spend much time there. Op has a list of provider and another query to get random clients from those providers. Then looks like a `JOIN` is required

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza -- I've no idea, it was easy to take his queries (which had errors) and make the "work" with my answer -- as above.  I don't know why you think a warning was needed.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to provide more detail. Edit your question to show the output from your two queries and the expected results.

As a guess....

IF you have a query for providers such as

```
SELECT DISTINCT Provider from myProviders
```

and it returns

```
Provider
========
ProviderA
ProviderB
ProviderC
```

and your random client query is something like

```
SELECT ClientName from myCLients WHERE <<my criteria>>
```

and it return something like

```
ClientName
==========
ClientA
ClientB
```

...then you can do something like

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Provider from myProviders)
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT ClientName from myCLients WHERE <<my criteria>>)
```

which will give you

```
Provider    ClientName
=========   ==========
ProviderA   ClientA
ProviderA   ClientB
ProviderB   ClientA
ProviderB   ClientB
ProviderC   ClientA
ProviderC   ClientB
```

Comment: This answer is a nice guide. But you need get `provider_id` too so you can join with the second query. The idea is get clientes from each provider.

Comment: When I posted the answer, the OP had not posted queries or (and still hasn't) desired output. OP needs to show desired output or we will just continue to guess.

Comment: This is the output I desire- however I cannot Union all or Cross join. The provider list is pulled from Provider_mstr table and the client list is pulled from the person table.

Comment: You can still `CROSS JOIN`. Change your two queries to output to two temporary tables e.g. `SELECT DISTINCT ColumnA, ColumnB INTO #Providers FROM myProviderTable' Do the same with you clients then just cross join the two temp tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
Dis_provider AS (
SELECT distinct provider_mstr.description 
FROM person 
INNER JOIN charges ON person.person_id = charges.person_id 
full JOIN provider_mstr ON provider_mstr.provider_id = charges.rendering_id 
where provider_mstr.delete_ind <> 'Y' )
Rando_Cient AS (
SELECT top 2 person.last_name + ', ' + person.first_name + ' ' + person.middle_name as 'Client', 
FROM person 
INNER JOIN charges ON person.person_id = charges.person_id 
INNER JOIN service_item_mstr ON charges.service_item_lib_id = service_item_mstr.service_item_lib_id 
FULL OUTER JOIN provider_mstr ON provider_mstr.provider_id = charges.rendering_id 
WHERE provider_mstr.delete_ind <> 'Y' and charges.amt > 0.01 
order by newid() )
Select 
provider_mstr.description,
Client
from Dis_Provider,Rando_Cient
```

And I would like if you provide us with more informations such as :

- an overview of the tables we gonna use
- The output desired